# Display the album cover of an Audio file with Kotlin - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I've seen a lot of people ask questions related to this, but they were all written in Java and they all use the method `getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(imageUri, thumbSize, null);`, but how to use `loadThumbnail()` in Kotlin?

Here is my attempt:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
    val displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameColumn)
    val album = cursor.getString(albumColumn)
    val albumId = cursor.getLong(albumIdColumn)
    val duration = cursor.getString(durationColumn)
    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id
    )
    val albumUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, albumId
    )
    val albumCover = ContentResolver().loadThumbnail(
        albumUri,
        Size(100, 100),
        null
    )
    val song = Song(id, displayName, album, albumId, duration, contentUri, albumUri, 
        albumCover.asImageBitmap())
    songs += song

    Log.v(TAG, "Added song：${song.displayName}")
}
```

Then Android studio prompted me with an error about ContentResolver():

> Cannot create an instance of an abstract class

So how do I use `loadThumbnail()` appropriately?

Thank you!

Comment: The same Java code will work in Kotlin. Or you can use the property-converted version which would be `contentResolver` (no initial capital letter and no parentheses).